# CSS Table Border

Tags: html, css, html-table

HI take a look at this simple code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8GsZa/

What I want is something like this:

[image]

By adding the `.tborder` class to `tr` or `td` wont work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use css `border-collapse` property , that may fix your problem

```
.tborder
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.tborder,.tborder td,.tborder th
{
    border:1px solid #427BD6;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8GsZa/18/)

Comment: This is the best way to do it

Answer (score 2):

[Demo Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8GsZa/2/)

mention `.tborder tr td` in your css

```
    .tborder tr td
    {
       border:1px solid #427BD6;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           <table border="0" class="tborder" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">Title1</td>
                        <td align="center">Title2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>test1</td>
                         <td>test2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

.tborder tr td{
  border:1px solid #427BD6;
  }
```